# How To add table class in th tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I have more data in a table and am using a search filter to sort the data.  I have many columns. In the search filter, it searches all columns. I want to set a particular column to have a search filter.

Here's the code for the table and column name:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered  dataTables-example" data-page-size="8" data-filter=#filter>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>

                                    <th>CREATION DATE</th>
                                    <th>TRANS DATE</th>


                                    <th>SHEET_NAME</th>


                                    <th>REIMBURSEMENT</th>
                                    <th>EXPENSE TYPE</th>
                                    <th>AMOUNT</th>
                                    <th>DEPTID</th>

                                    @*<th>DESCR</th>*@

                                    <th>DESCR254</th>

                                    <th>OUT OF POLICY</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (MonthlyDetailReport item in Model)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        @*<td>@item.SHEET_ID</td>*@
                                        <td>@item.H_CREATION_DT</td>
                                        <td>@item.I_TRANS_DT</td>

                                        <td>@item.SHEET_NAME</td>

                                        <td>@item.REIMBURSEMENT_CD </td>
                                        <td>@item.EXPENSE_TYPE</td>
                                        <td>@item.MONETARY_AMOUNT</td>
                                        <td>@item.DEPTID</td>

                                        <td>@item.DESCR254</td>

                                        <td>@item.OUT_OF_POLICY</td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="5">
                                        <ul class="pagination pull-right"></ul>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
```

Jquery code for filter search common:

```
  $('.dataTables-example').DataTable({
                dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
                buttons: [
                    { extend: 'copy' },
                    { extend: 'csv' },
                    { extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile' },
                    { extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile' },

                    {
                        extend: 'print',
                        customize: function (win) {
                            $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                            $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

                            $(win.document.body).find('table')
                                    .addClass('compact')
                                    .css('font-size', 'inherit');
                        }
                    }
                ]

            });
```

I want table class all `<th> html tag`, how can I add this ? How to filter search every column?

Comment: Check if this link is useful https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40981/filtering-multiple-columns#Comment_106559